# Проблема реализации последовательности Таймеров

Tags: java, android

Приложение должно загружать `MediaPlayer`, затем `Vice recognition`, если голос будет равен (`equals`) слову в условии `if`, то это слово ставится в `TextView` и загружается другой `Voice recognition`. Если не равно, то неверное слово ставится в `TextView` и загружается `MediaPlayer`.

Столкнулся с проблемой в методе `onActivityResult` при реализации условия `switch` выполняется `case 1`, но не выполняется `case 2`, загружает `Voice recognition`, но не распознает. Не могу понять, в чем именно проблема.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MediaPlayer voice = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.carMercedes);
            voice.start();
            voice.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer voice) {
                    voice.release();
                    Timer timer = new Timer("1");
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
                            int timerId=Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            startActivityForResult(intent, timerId);
                        }
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            str += results.get(i);
        }
        if (str.equals("mercedes")) {
            rightAnswer();
            speechText.setText(str);
        } else {
            wrongAnswer();
            speechText.setText(str);
        }
    }
            case 2:
                if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    ArrayList<String> results;
                    results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    String str = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                        str += results.get(i);
                    }
                if (str.equals("maserati")) {
                    speechText.setText(str);
                } else {
                    speechText.setText(str);
                }
        }
    }
    }

private void wrongAnswer() {
    MediaPlayer voice = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.carMaserati);
    voice.start();
    voice.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer voice) {
            voice.release();
        }
    });
}
private void rightAnswer() {
    Timer timer = new Timer("2");
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
            int timerId=Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName());//получаем идентификатор таймера
            startActivityForResult(intent, timerId);//засылаем его в Intent
        }
    }, 0);
}
}
```

Comment: 1) После `case` нужен `break`. 2) Зачем вы проверяете `requestCode == 1 ` ,если у вас и так уже `case 1:`?

Comment: Да не за что. Добавил ответ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) После `case` нужен `break`.

2) Зачем вы проверяете `requestCode == 1` ,если у вас и так уже `case 1:` перед этим стоит.

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос: при первом запуске распознования если я отвечаю maserati, то он первый case пропускает, как сделать строгую последовательность распознования, чтобы при первом case если я отвечаю maserati, он бы считал это неправильным?

Comment: @Nikolai лучше как отдельный вопрос наверно задать.

Comment: если вы знаете ответ на мой вопрос можете ответить [перейдя по ссылке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476658/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-switch-case) и получить +50 к репутации +1 к карме)

Comment: @Nikolai хорошо )