# Как сделать строгую последовательность Таймеров (switch/case)

Tags: java, android

Приложение загружает `MediaPlayer`, затем `Voice recognition`, если голос равен (`equals`) слову в условии `if`, то это слово ставится в `TextView` и загружается другой `Voice recognition`. Если не равно, то неверное слово ставится в `TextView` и загружается `MediaPlayer`.

При первом запуске распознавания, если я отвечаю `maserati`, то он пропускает `case 1` и сразу переходит к `case 2`.

Как сделать СТРОГУЮ последовательность распознавания, чтобы он начинал распознавать с `case 1`, а это значит, если я отвечаю `maserati`, то он должен считать это неправильным?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MediaPlayer voice = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.carMercedes);
            voice.start();
            voice.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer voice) {
                    voice.release();
                    Timer timer = new Timer("1");
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
                            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
                            int timerId=Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            startActivityForResult(intent, timerId);
                        }
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> results;
            results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            String str = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                str += results.get(i);
            }
            if (str.equals("mercedes")) {
                rightAnswer();
                speechText.setText(str);
            } else {
                wrongAnswer();
                speechText.setText(str);
            }
        }
    break;
        case 2:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> results;
            results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            TextView speechText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            String str = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                str += results.get(i);
            }
        if (str.equals("maserati")) {
            speechText.setText(str);
        } else {
            speechText.setText(str);
        }
    }
    break;
        }
        }

private void wrongAnswer() {
    MediaPlayer voice = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.carMaserati);
    voice.start();
    voice.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer voice) {
            voice.release();
        }
    });
}
private void rightAnswer() {
    Timer timer = new Timer("2");
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
            int timerId=Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            startActivityForResult(intent, timerId);
        }
    }, 0);
}
}
```

P/s. Если ответ вам неизвестен, пожалуйста, плюсуйте вопрос.

Comment: Не понятно почему при `maserati` пропускается `case1` и если даже так, то почему не проверять это перед `switch`?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо за ответ, а как это реализовать, если у меня, допустим, 10 таймером с voice recognition будет?

Comment: А в мгновенном запуске заданий в таймере (вызов `.schedule( runnable, 0)`) есть какой-то смысл? Я правильно понимаю, что программа представляет собой последовательность вопросов, ответы на которые пользователь должен произнести?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы стартуете `Activity` на распознавание:

```
int timerId=Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName());
startActivityForResult(intent, timerId);
```

У вас тут `id` потока равно `1`.

В итоге в `onActivityResult` у вас и получается в `requestCode` единица и срабатывает первый `case`. Если вы, скажем, сделаете так:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Тогда в `onActivityResult` у вас сработает второй `case`.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ!

Comment: @Nikolai да не за что. При новых вопросах по Android лучше в комментариях пинганите меня по нику, чтоб мне уведомление пришло. А то не всегда есть время на просмотр всех вопросов )

Comment: Добрый день, у меня появился [Новый Вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509425/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-textview/509510#509510), посмотрите плиз, +1 к карме и +50 к репутации)